# Cannot figure out TypeScript error TS2304: Cannot find name

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used the following code to assign the `loadedIngredient` an object through this code.

The code I used is

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Ingredient } from '../../shared/Ingredient.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-list-edit',
  templateUrl: './shopping-list-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-list-edit.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingListEditComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('name') ingredientName:ElementRef;
   @ViewChild('amount') ingredientAmount:ElementRef;
   @Output() inputValue = new EventEmitter<Ingredient>();


   constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSubmit(){
    const iname = this.ingredientName.nativeElement.value;
    const iamount = this.ingredientAmount.nativeElement.value;
    loadedIngredient:Ingredient = new Ingredient(iname,iamount);
    this.inputValue.emit(loadedIngredient);
  }

}
```

The errors that keep popping up is.

```
ERROR in src/app/shopping-list/shopping-list-edit/shopping-list-edit.component.t s(21,4): error TS7028: Unused label. src/app/shopping-list/shopping-list-edit/shopping-list-edit.component.ts(21,21): error TS2539: Cannot assign to 'Ingredient' because it is not a variable. src/app/shopping-list/shopping-list-edit/shopping-list-edit.component.ts(22,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'loadedIngredient'.
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively you are attempting to reference an undeclared variable by the looks of it, which TypeScript will treat as an error. One solution is you could initialize a class property `loadedIngredient` and reference with `this` in methods such as `onSubmit()`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Ingredient } from '../../shared/Ingredient.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-list-edit',
  templateUrl: './shopping-list-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-list-edit.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingListEditComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('name') ingredientName:ElementRef;
   @ViewChild('amount') ingredientAmount:ElementRef;
   @Output() inputValue = new EventEmitter<Ingredient>();

   loadedIngredient: Ingredient;

   constructor() { }

   ngOnInit() {}

   onSubmit(){
     const iname = this.ingredientName.nativeElement.value;
     const iamount = this.ingredientAmount.nativeElement.value;
     this.loadedIngredient: Ingredient = new Ingredient(iname, iamount);
     this.inputValue.emit(this.loadedIngredient);
   }    
}
```

Or you need to specify a variable scope such as `var`, `let`, `const` for the local variable `loadedIngredient` within `onSubmit()`:

```
onSubmit(){
  const iname = this.ingredientName.nativeElement.value;
  const iamount = this.ingredientAmount.nativeElement.value;
  const loadedIngredient: Ingredient = new Ingredient(iname, iamount);
  this.inputValue.emit(this.loadedIngredient);
}
```

Thanks to the generous @lealceldeiro, here a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-loadedingredient-non-declared?embed=1) demonstrating the error/solution.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Right.... I was making a demo... [**See this**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-loadedingredient-non-declared?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: That's a great demo. You should submit your answer, seeing it in a StackBlitz could really help the asker.

Comment: Feel free to use it in your own answer since you explained in more detail other alternative too. I won't delete it anyway :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Glad to help! Mark the answer that helped you resolve your issue. Thanks!